# cron job for every half hour

Tags: shell, cron, debian

i have to run a shell script as cron job

in VERY HALF HOUR but ONLY IN BETWEEN (morning 10.30 A.M to evening 6.30 A.M)
DAILY

means this cron job will be execute every half only within a scpecfic givine time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
30 10 * * * <your cronjob>
0,30 11-18 * * * <your cronjob>
```

Note you can also use the following for every 30 min:

```
*/30 11-18 * * * <your cronjob>
```